# Bayesian Model: Find minimum value of mu

Tags: model, bayesian, winbugs

I have been trying to solve a problem using bayesian methods, but I can't figure out how to write the model.

I am trying to find the value mu such that x = mu + Error, Error ~ Gamma(a, b) (or some other distribution).

Basically I want to be able to say something like:

```
for(i in 1:N) {
  x[i] <- mu + tau[i]
  tau[i] ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
}
mu ~ dunif(0.0, 1000)
```

However, this doesn't work because x[i] needs to have a distribution, and I can't think of how to make this happen (I have tried making x[i] ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001), but this doesn't a. constrain x to being > mu, and b. doesn't help me to estimate mu.

If you could help it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify where your data comes in? Perhaps give the full model or relate how x connects to the data?

Comment: Hi @gjabel, x is time recordings for some particular activity, so there will be some 'minimum' time it can be done in, which is what I'm interested in knowing. Of course, the data (x) will be distributed above this value, and be something like a gamma or lognormal distribution that starts at this value (mu), with most values slightly above and tapering off. I've been looking around online but haven't managed to find something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you should derive the minimum (mu) of the values of x outside of BUGS and pass it as part of the data or just give tau directly. This is necessary as the min function in BUGS will not work on an entire vector. Perhaps a model (and data) such as this is what appropriate:

```
#BUGS model
model{
    #data manipulations
    for(i in 1:N){
        tau[i] <- x[i]-mu
    }

    #model
    for(i  in 1:N){
        y[i] ~ dlnorm(tau[i], y.tol)
        log.y[i] <- log(y[i])
    }

    #prior
    y.tol ~ dunif(0,1000)
}

#data
list(x=c(5,3,8,9,3,6,8,2,4,11), N=10, mu=2)
```

Another thought I have had, is that perhaps you want to model the minimum as type of extreme value modelling exercise? In that case, you should check out dgev in OpenBUGS.

Comment: Thanks @gjabel, this is helpful. Doesn't exactly help to estimate the 'minimum' possible value of 'x', but I'll try fiddle around with it and see where it gets me.